# Moving all nodes the same time including links?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

in D3.js I use the force-layout to shift all nodes to the right with this code below. But when call the function, only the nodes shift, the text and links stay the same. What exactly is missing here? Is it the tick() function that has to be called inside the function?

```
  function(){ d3.select(".nodes").attr("transform", "translate(200,0)");

                simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();


};

        simulation
                    .nodes(nodes)
                    .on("tick", function(d)
                    {

                      link
                        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                      node
                        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

                     text
                        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; }) 
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });



                    }

                    );

                simulation.force("link")
                    .links(links);

              });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function only moves the g that contains the nodes. It doesn't update the underlying data (d.x and d.y) that is attached to the nodes. So while they visually move, it isn't because the force (or your code) has updated the d.x or d.y values.

Answer (score 1):

As @TomShanley said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44915515/5768908), you are only translating the containing `<g>` elements.

Don't do that. The idiomatic way to move the nodes for a fixed position is setting `fx` and `fy` or, alternatively, using `forceY` and `forceY` (both in D3 v4).

This is a demo using `forceX`. First, we remove the `center` force, then we set `forceX` to a position at the right:

```
simulation.force("center", null)
simulation.force("toRight", d3.forceX(360).strength(0.8))
```

Here is the demo, click the button to move the nodes, links and texts:

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  name: "foo",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "bar",
  color: "green"
}, {
  name: "baz",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "foofoo",
  color: "yellow"
}, {
  name: "foobar",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  name: "foobaz",
  color: "green"
}, {
  name: "barfoo",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "barbar",
  color: "yellow"
}, {
  name: "barbaz",
  color: "blue"
}];

var links = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 3
}, {
  "source": 1,
  "target": 3
}, {
  "source": 1,
  "target": 4
}, {
  "source": 2,
  "target": 5
}, {
  "source": 3,
  "target": 6
}, {
  "source": 1,
  "target": 7
}, {
  "source": 6,
  "target": 8
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 7
}, {
  "source": 2,
  "target": 6
}, {
  "source": 3,
  "target": 8
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.r + 1;
  }));

var link = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1);

var node = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r = 10;
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color
  })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));;

var text = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("dy", "-1em")
  .attr("dx", "-1em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(links);

simulation.on("tick", function() {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  }).attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

  text.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {
  simulation.force("center", null)
  simulation.force("toRight", d3.forceX(360).strength(0.8))
  simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<br>
```